# Google maps & fusion table api - mouseover on 2 layers

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion map with 2 layers, that are points representing US towns. The 2 layers have similar data, but the towns are different. I enabled mouseover effect on both layers. Sometimes, when 2 towns are displayed one on top of the other (on a large scale map), the 2 mouseover events fire and 2 labels show up at the same time, one on top of the other.
Is there a way to trigger just 1 mouseover event at a time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write code in your mouseover event handlers to prevent more than one being triggered at a time.

Comment: I tried it by using the "clearListeners" , but it didn't have any effect. I didn't find anything like "deleteEvent" in the google map api.
It actually looks like the mouseover event fires even without adding the listener, but just by calling the "enableMapTips"

Comment: That is part of the fusiontips extention.  You will need to modify the fusiontips extension.